# Dynamic absolute position divs won't resize section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a section with a white background, and since my articles resize dynamically based on JavaScript, they are outside the section for some reason, and to make matters worse, my gradient repeats.

A quick solution is

```
section {
height:1000px;
}
```

However, the JavaScript goes outside of that, and makes the gradient repeat anyways.

http://jsfiddle.net/otanan/82kGe/

I'm open to recoding the whole thing if there's a more efficient way! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually resolved it after nearly another hour of fiddling by changing the article's position to relative and absolute!

### Thank you